# simple addition using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This statement `document.getElementById=count` is getting executed and showing result inside while loop only. outside the while loop this statement doesn't show any result what is the reason?

Here is my Screenshot

[image]

Comment: paste the code here.. so that we can check it and modify according to that

Comment: Represent Your Code in Standard Way.

Comment: You need to provide entire code with expected and actual result and learn basic formatting that stackoverflow supports so others can easily understand and provide possible answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var count = 0;

    x = x.match(/[+\-]*(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)/g) || [];

    while (x.length) {
        count += parseFloat(x.shift());
    }

    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" />
<button onclick="add()">Try</button>
<p id="demo1">para</p>
```